# non-numeric argument to binary operator (but argument IS numeric indeed)

Tags: r, graph

The dataset contains stats of teams in MLB matches. All of them are numeric.

```
   best <- lm(mlb11$runs ~  mlb11$bat_avg )
summary(best)

plot(mlb11$bat_avg, mlb11$runs) +
abline(best)

qqnorm(resid(best)) +
qqline(resid(best))

class(resid(best))
```

The qqnorm and qqline just never worked when connected with the "+".

The last line of code returns "numeric", so I think this error message makes no sense. I actually followed every step on a tutorial but could not add the line to the graph. This is so strange!

**follow up:**
If I removed the "+" between qqline and qqnorm, it returned "Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet"

**follow up:**
when I entered

```
qqnorm(resid(best)) +
qqline(resid(best))
```

The right graph did show up in my R window. However, when I tried to knit the rmd file, it stopped on that line and showed the error message. So weird. Would this be a software/system problem?

Comment: `resid(best)` returns the residuals from the model. "Residuals" are the difference between the observed value of the dependent variable and the predicted value (per the regression), so is by necessity of class `numeric`. Your statement *"The qqnorm and qqline just never worked together"* is unclear: what is wrong about that? If we see no data, no plots, and no errors/warnings/output, then it's all speculation.

Comment: `qqnorm + qqline` is the part giving you the error. You can't add `+` base R plots together like that. Just run `qqnorm(resid(best))` then run `qqline(resid(best))` separately.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks! I tried your way but it returned "Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet"

Comment: @r2evans Thanks! The data are all numbers from mlb matches.

Comment: @JessiePeng - `qqnorm` has to be run first as it creates a plot window (don't close it!) then run `qqline` which will add a line to the plot. I can confirm this works with `qqnorm(1:10); qqline(1:10)` for instance.

Comment: @thelatemail Thank you! It did work in my R window, but I can't knit it from rmd to word document as the knitting always stops at the qqline telling me "non0numeric argument added to numeric operator

Comment: @JessiePeng - the only reason I can think you would get that error is if you still have the `+` sign in your rmd document. (The error message is complaining about giving something that is not a number to the `+` function). Please check you've removed it.

Comment: Remove the `+` signs altogether. They shouldn't be there anywhere. At all.